# How can I check if an gmail account is taken using AJAX or JS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, email, gmail

I'm trying to write a program that can check if a gmail address is taken or not.
Right now I can use Terminal to check if a gmail address is taken or not.

```
$ telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 173.194.204.26...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP a3si10427297qtj.266 - gsmtp
helo gmail
250 mx.google.com at your service
mail from: <randomgmailaddress@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK a3si10427297qtj.266 - gsmtp
rcpt to: <randomgmailaddress@gmail.com>
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser a3si10427297qtj.266 - gsmtp
^]
telnet> q
Connection closed.
```

However, I want to be able to do this or use another method in a simple JS function that can check if an email has been taken or not. How can I do this?

Comment: You want to do this in nodejs obviously - there's libraries for SMTP in nodejs - if you want to do this in a browser, don't bother

Comment: is there any way for me to do this without node?

Comment: yes, there's python, php, Perl ... I could list hundreds more - you just won't be able to do this directly in the browser

Comment: is there any way for me to embed the PHP into JS?

Comment: so, I take it you want to do this in a browser? PHP doesn't run in a browser, it runs on a server - as I said in my first comment, *if you want to do this in a browser, don't bother*